# Trying to call pure virtual function from pybrind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am trying to implement an abstract class using pybind11. What I have is the following:

Base class

```
namespace VNCS
{
class BlendingField : public sofa::core::objectmodel::BaseObject
{
public:
    SOFA_CLASS(BlendingField, sofa::core::objectmodel::BaseObject);
    BlendingField() = default;
    virtual ~BlendingField() = default;

    virtual Real blending(const VNCS::Point_3 &p) const = 0;
};

}  // namespace VNCS
```

and implementation

```
namespace VNCS
{
namespace py
{
namespace module
{
void blendingField(pybind11::module &m);
}

class BlendingField : public VNCS::BlendingField
{
public:
    SOFA_CLASS(VNCS::py::BlendingField, VNCS::BlendingField);
    BlendingField();
    ~BlendingField() override;

    VNCS::Real blending(const VNCS::Point_3 &p) const final;
};

}  // namespace py
}  // namespace VNCS
```

with the following implementations

```
PYBIND11_DECLARE_HOLDER_TYPE(T, sofa::core::sptr<T>, true);

VNCS::py::BlendingField::BlendingField()
    : VNCS::BlendingField()
{
}

VNCS::py::BlendingField::~BlendingField()
{
}

VNCS::Real VNCS::py::BlendingField::blending(const VNCS::Point_3 &p) const
{
    const std::array<double, 3> pyP{p[0], p[1], p[2]};
    PYBIND11_OVERLOAD_PURE(VNCS::Real,          /* Return type */
                           VNCS::BlendingField, /* Parent class */
                           blending,            /* Name of function in C++ (must match Python name) */
                           pyP                  /* Argument(s) */
    )
}

void VNCS::py::module::blendingField(pybind11::module &m)
{
    pybind11::class_<VNCS::BlendingField, sofa::core::objectmodel::BaseObject, sofa::core::sptr<VNCS::BlendingField>>(
        m, "BlendingFieldBase");

    pybind11::class_<VNCS::py::BlendingField, VNCS::BlendingField, sofa::core::sptr<VNCS::py::BlendingField>>(
        m, "BlendingField")
        .def(pybind11::init(
            [](pybind11::args & /*args*/, pybind11::kwargs &kwargs) { return new VNCS::py::BlendingField(); }))
        .def("blending", &VNCS::BlendingField::blending);
}
```

This works fine if I create a python file, load my module, create a `BlendingField(PyVNCS.BlendingField)` and call `blending(self, point)`, but if I call the python file from the C++ side using an interpreter (this happens from another library), get a pointer to the blending field and try to call blending() virtual, it fails with the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Tried to call pure virtual function "VNCS::BlendingField::blending"
```

I dont understand why this is happening, since debugging the C++ side clearly shows that Im entering the VNCS::py::BlendingField::blending implementation.

What is happening here?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  It appears to be a lifetime issue.  I expect that by taking shared_ptr argument that I don't have to do the keep_alive thing, but I tried anyway.  The instance that I get passed to my container is valid, but when I use it later it no longer exists and so the standard macros end up calling base it seems??

Comment: This issue is repeated again and again in pybind github. I actually didnt solve correctly, but since I did some refactoring on how my python scripts work, I was able to perform all the operations that needed the BlendingField while keeping it in scope. That solved the issue for me